# Black screen on iPad retina display

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I've a problem with a little game application running on iPad. When I lunch the simulator iOS 5.1 with iPad retina display, the application start with my default image @x2 and after show the image go to a black screen. In normal iPad iOS 5.1 simulator run well. Xcode tell me only this:

```
2012-04-25 14:24:26.978 AppName[83696:10a03] cocos2d: Frame interval: 1
2012-04-25 14:24:26.980 AppName[83696:10a03] cocos2d: surface size: 1536x2048
```

Any idea?
Thank you

---

@Smamim Hossain: Same error I put my full Appdelegate.m

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GameConfig.h"
#import "Intro.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void) removeStartupFlicker
{

//#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController


//#endif // GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController  
}
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application

[director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D]
{


    // Init the window
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];

    [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D]
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    // Init the View Controller
    viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    //
    // Create the EAGLView manually
    //  1. Create a RGB565 format. Alternative: RGBA8
    //  2. depth format of 0 bit. Use 16 or 24 bit for 3d effects, like CCPageTurnTransition
    //
    //
    EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                        ];

//  // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");


#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
#else
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
#endif

    [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [director setDisplayFPS:NO];
    [director setDepthTest:NO];

    // make the OpenGLView a child of the view controller
    [viewController setView:glView];

    // make the View Controller a child of the main window
    [window addSubview: viewController.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];


    // Removes the startup flicker
    [self removeStartupFlicker];

    // Run the intro Scene
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [Intro scene]];
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
}

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    [[director openGLView] removeFromSuperview];

    [viewController release];

    [window release];

    [director end]; 
}

- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNextDeltaTimeZero:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: What version of cocos2d-iphone are you using?

Comment: @Halley cocos2d-iphone-2.0-rc1

Comment: Can you give me more details? I have to know how you implemented your scene such as its position and anchor point. Also, have you enabled retina display properly in AppDelegate?

Comment: @Halley in my Appdelegate.m I have this: if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
  CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

Answer (score 13):

try this line of code at
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

[director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];

hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for help, now I have this: } - (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D] { But an error is shown : Expected method body –

Comment: just add this line [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D]; at applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Comment: it didn't helped is there any particular location where i should set it!

Comment: it is the best solution!