# iPad screen size always 1024x768, even on retina and Air

Tags: ipad, screen, resolution, retina-display

I want to test my app to make sure the images display properly on a 1536x2048 landscape. I have an NSLog statement output the screen height to verify.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
NSLog(@"height: %f",self.frame.size.height);
```

However, it always shows that the height is 768, even if I use a physical iPad Air or any of the simulators. As I understand it, the Air and retina devices should show a height of 1536.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncommenting a line of code in AppDelegate.m as follows, allows you to set surface size 1536x2048; obviously you have to provide a valid "image~ipad-hd.png" file in your resources.

```
 // // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
        if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] ) CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
```

The bad new is that in return, you'll get a totally black screen on ipad hires simulators; but I solved! Answers are already in stackoverflow here: [Black screen on iPad retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315659/black-screen-on-ipad-retina-display)

You have to add another line of code like this as user Shamim Hossain's suggestion:

```
//  // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] ) CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
```